# c# Generic function as a parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have this function:

```
private async Task Wizardry<T>(Func<T theParameter, Task> method)
{
    try
    {
        await method(theParameter);
    }
    catch
    { }
}
```

and the way I see it working is like this:

```
await this.Wizardry<Email>(this.emailProvider.SendAsync(email));
await this.Wizardry<Log>(this.SaveLog(log));
```

but obviously that does not work.
Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Is `T theParameter` correct in above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create a `Func` where you want to pass in parameters while you haven't got any parameters to pass in.

A non-generic `Func<Task>` will do:

```
await this.Wizardry(() => this.emailProvider.SendAsync(email));
await this.Wizardry(() => this.SaveLog(log));

private async Task Wizardry(Func<Task> method)
{
    await method();
}
```

Comment: should that be `await this.Wizardry<Email>(() => this.emailProvider.SendAsync(email));`

Comment: No. There are no generics involved here. They have no use.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Why you are not sending parameter to the method? That is not what OP need as I see it. His method needs 1 parameter as input.

Comment: Why? There is no point in making this generic and passing parameters. The code will work without it. @3615

Comment: @PatrickHofman, Ok, I got your point now. Well, the only reason to do it like OP wants - perform some changes to the parameter before sending it.

Comment: Since the method is not generic, you should remove the `<T>`

Comment: should the method be `private async Task Wizardry(Func<Task> method)` then, if we don't require generics?

Comment: @r3plica definitely yes.

Comment: @Dennis_E oh yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need:

```
    private async Task Wizardry<T>(Func<T, Task> method, T theParameter)
    {
        try
        {
            await method(theParameter);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

And invoke it like:

```
await this.Wizardry<string>((z)=> Task.Run(()=>Console.WriteLine(z)), "test");
```

Comment: I've added the example of invocation, but I guess you already figured that out by yourself:)

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 possibilities:

```
private async Task Wizardry(Func<Task> method) {
    try {
        await method();
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Which is called with:

```
this.Wizardry(() => this.emailProvider.SendAsync(email));
```

Or

```
private async Task Wizardry<T>(Func<T, Task> method, T theParameter) {
    try {
        await method(theParameter);
    } catch {
    }
}
```

Which is called with:

```
this.Wizardry(this.emailProvider.SendAsync, email);
```